# .NET Core Web API Newtonsoft.Json Nuget Dependency Warning

Tags: asp.net-core, msbuild, json.net, asp.net-core-webapi, nuget-package

I have the following Web API solution structure with three projects in a .NET 5 Web Api

```
.  
+-- Api.csproj  
|   +-- Dependencies
|   |   +-- Projects
|   |   |   +-- Infrastructure.csproj
|   |   |   |   +-- Dependencies
|   |   |   |   |   +-- Projects
|   |   |   |   |   |   +-- Core.csproj
|   |   |   |   |   +-- Packages
|   |   |   |   |   |   +-- Serilog.Sinks.Telegram (2.0.1)
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   +-- Newtonsoft.Json (11.0.2)
```

When I build `Infrastructure.csproj`, it succeeds, but 2 strange issues

- Build warning `Infrastructure.csproj : warning NU1603: Serilog.Sinks.TelegramClient 2.0.1 depends on Newtonsoft.Json (>= 10.0.0) but Newtonsoft.Json 10.0.0 was not found. An approximate best match of Newtonsoft.Json 10.0.1 was resolved.`
- Looking in the `\debug` folder, I don't see any dlls for Serilog or Newtonsoft.

When I build `Api.csproj`, it succeeds, but again strange issues

- Build warning `Infrastructure.csproj : warning NU1603: Serilog.Sinks.TelegramClient 2.0.1 depends on Newtonsoft.Json (>= 10.0.0) but Newtonsoft.Json 10.0.0 was not found. An approximate best match of Newtonsoft.Json 10.0.1 was resolved.`
- Build warning `Api.csproj : warning NU1603: Serilog.Sinks.TelegramClient 2.0.1 depends on Newtonsoft.Json (>= 10.0.0) but Newtonsoft.Json 10.0.0 was not found. An approximate best match of Newtonsoft.Json 10.0.1 was resolved.`
- Looking in the `\debug` folder of the Api.csproj, I **do** see Serilog and Newtonsoft dlls.
- The Newtonsoft dll in debug has a version of 12.0.3.*

My Questions:

1. Is it right that there are no Serilog or Newtonsoft dlls in Infrastructure.csproj output folder?
2. Why am I getting a warning about Newtonsoft for the Api.csproj build when the dll is correctly put into output folder and the version is greater than the warning?